# How is pipelining implemented? Can we read the firmware of a modern microprocessor?

Tags: firmware, microprocessors

My question has two related parts.

**First**, most of modern microprocessors implement pipelining and other means to execute code faster. How do they implement it? I mean, is it the firmware or something else?

**Second**, if it is the firmware, is it possible for me to read the firmware and look at the code?

Apologies if it is stupid as I have little idea of microprocessor.

Comment: Something else.  It's done to the firmware by the microprocessor.  Sometimes with very interesting side effects ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipelining in processor design is a hardware concept; the idea that a stream of instructions can execute faster if it exploits a bit of parallelism in the flow for process and instruction and by breaking up critical paths in logic. In hardware, for a given design (technically it's implementation), you can only "run" it so fast; ie it takes some time for signals to propagate through all the logic. The longest time it could take in the worst case is the critical path and defines a maximum time (or frequency) the design can run (this is were maximum clock speed comes from).

Now, processing an instruction in the simplest processor can be broken into three big parts: fetching the instruction from memory (ie, fetch), decoding the instruction into it's parts (decode), and actually executing the instruction (execute). For every instruction, it is fetched, decoded, executed; then the next instruction, then the next instruction.

The hardware for each of these stages has a critical path, ie a maximum time it can take in the worst case (`Tmax_fetch` for fetch stage, `Tmax_decode` for decode, `Tmax_exec` for execute). So, for a processor without pipelining (or, single cycle), the critical path for the full processor is all these stages would be the sum of these critical paths (this isn't necessarily true in real designs, but we will use this as a simplified example), `Tmax_inst = Tmax_fetch + Tmax_decode + Tmax_exec`. So, to run through four instructions, it would take `4 * Tmax_inst = 4 * Tmax_fetch + 4 * Tmax_decode + 4 * Tmax_exec`.

Pipelining allows us to break up these critical paths using hardware registers (not unlike the programmers registers, `r2` in ARM is an example), but these registers are invisible to the firmware. Now, instead of `Tmax_inst` being the sum of the stages, it's now just three times the largest of the stages, `Tmax_inst = 3 * Tmax_stage = 3 * max(Tmax_fetch, Tmax_decode, Tmax_exec)` since the processor has to "wait" for the slowest stage to finish in the worst case. The processor is now slower for a single instruction, but due to the pipeline, we can do each of these stages independently as long as there isn't a dependency between the instructions being processed in each stsge (like a branch instruction, where the fetch stage can't run until the branch is executed). So, for four independent instructions, the processor will only take `Tmax_stage * (3 + 4 - 1)` as the pipeline allows the first instruction to be fetched, then decoded at the same time the second instruction is fetched, etc.

This should hopefully help better exolain pipelining, but to answer your questions directly:

1. It's a hardware design concept, so implemented in hardware, not firmware
2. As it's a hardware concept, there is no firmware code to read.